# How to set global prop in react apollo client

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am working with react and react-apollo client.

Here is my main route file

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component, isAuthed, ...rest }) => {
  console.log({ isAuthed })
  return (
    <Route {...rest} exact
      render = {(props) => (
        isAuthed ? (
          <div>
            {React.createElement(component, props)}
          </div>
        ) :
          (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: { from: props.location }
              }}
            />
          )
      )}
    />
  )
}

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isAuthed: false
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ isAuthed: true })
  }

  render() {
    const { isAuthed } = this.state
    return (
        <div style={{ direction: direction }}>
          <Header {...this.props} history={history}/>
          <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/dashboard" />} />
              <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
              <PrivateRoute isAuthed={isAuthed} path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
              <PrivateRoute isAuthed={isAuthed} path="/AdminManagement" component={Admin} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default compose(
  graphql(SET_SESSION, { name: 'setSession' })
)((withNamespaces)('common')(App))
```

Now when I do login inside the login component I need to set `isAuthed` to true which is inside my main route file(above one)

How can I do this with react apollo client?

Comment: This question lacks so much details... nobody can help you right now. What query ? What's `Login` ? Why apollo client ? How's your backend ?

Comment: @Treycos Don't go too deep. Just want to know how can I update/get  same `prop` in multiple components just  as we do with react redux

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no such thing as a "global" prop in React or Apollo. If you want to achieve something similar to your example (i.e. update the state on the root component from your login component), have you considered passing a method down to said component and firing it when your GraphQL mutation resolves?

I'm going to take a stab at this, but please note this is all pseudo code and just outlines one of the many approaches you could take to address this:

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userInfo: {},
            authed: false,
        }
        this.modifyUserInfo = this.modifyUserInfo.bind(this);
    }

    modifyUserInfo(userInfo) {
        this.setState(state => ({
            ...state,
            userInfo,
            authed: true,
        }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // Render all your routes and everything...
            <LoginComponent loginCb={modifyUserInfo} />
        )
    }
}
```

**Login Component**

```
const Login = props => {
    return (
            <Mutation mutation={loginMutation}>
                {(login) => {
                    <form onSubmit={(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        login()
                            .then(res => {
                                if (res.userInfo) {
                                    props.loginCb(res.userInfo);
                                }
                            })
                            .catch(err => {
                                console.log(err)
                            })
                    }}>
                        {/* Add the rest of your login form */}
                        <button type="submit"/>
                    </form>
                }}
            </Mutation>
    )
}
```

Rather than storing your user authentication information in your root state, have you considered using your Apollo Cache and injecting the user information into the relevant components? Like I said, there are many, many different ways to approach this.